# jQuery tabs plugin creates extra anchor tags when nesting hyperlink

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs, anchor

I am new to JavaScript and jQuery. While trying to nest anchor tags in the content div of a tabs plugin, extra empty actor tags are being created. How can I adapt the code to prevent this from happening. I have created a JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/p94aybey/

Thanks

```
<ul class="tabs" data-tabgroup="first-tab-group">
  <li><a href="#group1-tab1" class="active">Tab 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#group1-tab2">Tab 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#group1-tab3">Tab 3</a></li>
</ul>
<section id="first-tab-group" class="tabgroup">
  <div id="group1-tab1">
    <h2>Heading 1</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="group1-tab2">
    <h2>Heading 2</h2>
    <p>Adipisci autem obcaecati velit natus quos beatae explicabo.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="group1-tab3">
    <h2>Heading 3</h2>
    <p>Atque ratione soluta laboriosam illo inventore amet?</p>

    <a href="http://gogle.com" target="_blank">Link<a><br>
    <a href="http://gmail.com" target="_blank">Mail<a>
  </div>
</section>

<ul class="tabs" data-tabgroup="second-tab-group">
  <li><a href="#group2-tab1" class="active">Tab 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#group2-tab2">Tab 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#group2-tab3">Tab 3</a></li>
</ul>
<section id="second-tab-group" class="tabgroup">
  <div id="group2-tab1">
    <h2>Heading 1</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="group2-tab2">
    <h2>Heading 2</h2>
    <p>Adipisci autem obcaecati velit natus quos beatae explicabo.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="group2-tab3">
    <h2>Heading 3</h2>
    <p>Atque ratione soluta laboriosam illo inventore amet?</p>
  </div>
</section>

$('.tabgroup > div').hide();
$('.tabgroup > div:first-of-type').show();
$('.tabs a').mouseover(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this),
        tabgroup = '#'+$this.parents('.tabs').data('tabgroup'),
        others = $this.closest('li').siblings().children('a'),
        target = $this.attr('href');
    others.removeClass('active');
    $this.addClass('active');
    $(tabgroup).children('div').hide();
    $(target).show();

})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two closing anchor tags lacking slashes.

```
</a>
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/p94aybey/1/)

Note that I've combined your `hide()` and `show()` statements for simplicity, and I've removed the unnecessary `e.preventDefault()` statement.

Comment: Thank you! I feel silly for such a simple error... :P

Comment: Happens to all of us.